# Density of states from numerical integration and then differentiation

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

for some reason I want to calculate following expression:

$$
N(\omega) = \int \limits_{-\pi}^\pi \mathrm{d} x \int \limits_{-\pi}^\pi \mathrm{d} y \int \limits_{-\pi}^\pi \mathrm{d} z \; \delta \left( \omega - f(x,y,z) \right)
$$
where $f(x,y,z) = \sqrt{\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}+\sin^2 \frac{y}{2}+\sin^2 \frac{z}{2}}$. Of course, function $f$ might be similar to this, just starting from $f = 0$ at $x=y=z=0$ and $f>0$ in the cube $-\pi \leq x,y,z \leq \pi$.

However this is not possible not analytically nor numerically due to integrand being the Dirac delta function. So instead I took another function:

$$
G(\omega) = \int \limits_{-\pi}^\pi \mathrm{d} x \int \limits_{-\pi}^\pi \mathrm{d} y \int \limits_{-\pi}^\pi \mathrm{d} z \; \theta \left( \omega - f(x,y,z) \right)
$$
and the following holds true:
$$
N(\omega) = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} \omega} G(\omega)
$$

So I've setup a Mathematica code to calculate function $G$ (analytically possible only in 1D when $f(x) = \left| \sin \frac{x}{2} \right|$ and I want to see the result in 2D and 3D):

```
f[x_,y_,z_]:= Sqrt[Sin[x/2]^2+Sin[y/2]^2+Sin[z/2]^2];
G = Table[{omega, NIntegrate[HeavisideTheta[omega - f[x,y,z]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}]}, {omega, 0, 1.7, 0.01}];
```

Now the result is pretty function $G$ which can be plotted with a ListPlot, but what I am seeking is its derivative. So I finally calculate $N$:

```
DoS = Table[{G[[i, 1]], (G[[i + 1, 2]] - G[[i - 1, 2]])/(G[[i + 1, 1]] - G[[i - 1, 1]])}, {i, 2, Length[G] - 1}];
ListPlot[DoS]
```

This isn't very nice code, but it should work, right? No. Wrong. The result is very jerky function (and making step finer is not helping). What am I doing wrong? This kind of result is unexpected. I expect it to be more or less piecewise continuous function, like the analytical result I can get in 1D. Why it is not smooth in 2D and 3D? How can I get a correct, smooth numerical solution to $N (\omega)$? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `HeavisideTheta[]` with `UnitStep[]`?

Comment: Another symptom of the problem: `NIntegrate[...]` thinks $G$ is zero for $\omega<0.5$, even though for small $\omega$ it should be close to the volume of the sphere of radius $\omega/2$.

Comment: On the other hand, `g[ω_] := RegionMeasure@ImplicitRegion[f[x, y, z] <= ω, {{x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}}]` seems to gives better answers.

Comment: Really? Things like this are not doable numerically? No one knows how to pull this off?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way to "discretize" the problem is to approximate the delta function in some standard way, such as with a normal distribution or box function.  I'll show an approach with a box function. One advantage is that the inner integral is easy to compute, reducing the dimension of the numerical integration by one.

*Notes on the set-up:*
*1.*
I used the even symmetry of the integrand to reduce the integral to one over the cube $[0,\pi]^3$.
*2.*
The parameter `s` in `n[omega, s]` below determines the width of the unit box approximation to the Dirac delta function; the value `1/100` seemed to be a good compromise.
*3.*
I used `Reduce` to figure out the cases where the singular surface

```
f[x, y, z] == omega
```

intersects the cube and set up the limits of integration; the region of integration is restricted to the support of the inner integral. To simplify the work of `Reduce`, I used `a == Sin[x/2]`, and `b == Sin[y/2]` to convert the trigonometric problem to a polynomial one. The function `toPWCases` constructs, from the output of `Reduce`, the integrals for the different cases arising from the intersection of the singular surface with the sides of the cube for varying `omega`.
*4.*
Inactivating `NIntegrate` with [`Block[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) lets us construct the code for `n[omega, s]`, calling `Reduce` and `toPWCases` just once to break down the integration into its pieces.

```
ClearAll[f, n, i0, toPWCases];

f[x_, y_, z_] := Sqrt[Sin[x/2]^2 + Sin[y/2]^2 + Sin[z/2]^2];

Block[{NIntegrate, x, y, z, omega, s},
 i0[x_, y_, omega_, s_] = First@Differences[
       z /. Last@Solve[omega - f[x, y, z] == #, z] & /@ ({1, -1} s/2)
       ]/s /. ArcSin[a_] :> ArcSin@Sqrt[Clip[a^2, {0, 1}]] // 
   PiecewiseExpand;

 toPWCases[And[cond_, xr_, yr_]] := {NIntegrate[i0[x, y, omega, s],
     {x, 2 ArcSin@xr[[1]], 2 ArcSin@xr[[-1]]},
     {y, 2 ArcSin@yr[[1]], 2 ArcSin@yr[[-1]]}], cond} /.
   {a -> Sin[x/2], b -> Sin[y/2]};
 toPWCases[And[cond_, ranges_Or]] :=
   {Total[First@toPWCases[Hold && #] & /@ List @@ ranges], cond};

 n[omega_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ] = 8 Piecewise[
    toPWCases /@ List @@ Reduce[
       omega > 0 && 0 < a < 1 && 0 < b < 1 && omega^2 - (a^2 + b^2) > 0,
       {a, b}]
    ];
 ]
```

The integration is still a bit slow, even with the reduction in dimension. It can be sped up by around 100 sec. by adding the options `PrecisionGoal -> 4, AccuracyGoal -> 6` without a degradation of the plot.  A look at the output of `Reduce`, one can see that `omega == 1` and `omega == Sqrt[2]` divides the cases; we see, correspondingly, a change in the behavior of `n` near those values. Only once does `NIntegrate` complain about slow convergence, but it does not complain about the error.

```
Dynamic@omega

SessionTime[];
Plot[n[omega, 1/100], {omega, 0.1, 1.7}, PlotPoints -> 15, 
 MaxRecursion -> 1, PlotRange -> All, GridLines -> {{1, Sqrt[2]}, None}]
SessionTime[] - %%
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
(*  255.846962  <-- Timing *)
```

Note `MaxRecursion` is set to `1` for the sake of speed; a higher setting resolves the locations of the corners in the graph, which have a slight rounding, presumably due to the finite value `s = 1/100`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

`G` isn't just smooth enough.

```
f[x_, y_, z_] := Sqrt[Sin[x/2]^2 + Sin[y/2]^2 + Sin[z/2]^2];

G = ParallelTable[{omega, 
     NIntegrate[
      HeavisideTheta[omega - f[x, y, z]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, 
       Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]}, {omega, 0, 1.7,
      0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {441.301, Null}

For a first shot consider fitting a polynomial:

```
FitPolynomial[data_, n_] := Fit[data, Table[x^i, {i, 0, n}], x];
g[x_] := Evaluate@FitPolynomial[G, 10]

Show[ListPlot[G], Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 1.7}, PlotStyle -> Red], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Note, however, that for $\omega<0.41$, $G(\omega)$ is a numerical zero.

```
DoS = Table[{G[[i, 
      1]], (G[[i + 1, 2]] - G[[i - 1, 2]])/(G[[i + 1, 1]] - 
       G[[i - 1, 1]])}, {i, 2, Length[G] - 1}];
Show[ListPlot[DoS], 
  Plot[g'[x], {x, 0, 1.7}, PlotStyle -> Red], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

---

The finite difference method is implemented with an [undocumented function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html) (under *Spatial Derivative Approximations*):

```
{g1, g2} = Transpose @ G;
plot17 = ListPlot[#, Frame -> True] & @ Drop[#, -1] & @
  Transpose @ {g1, 
    NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], g1, g2, 
     DifferenceOrder -> 2]}
```

[image]

---

A polynomial isn't the best choice here, but one try other smoothing methods; try with `MovingAverage`:

```
G1 = MovingAverage[G, 5];
ListPlot[G1, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
DoS = Table[{G1[[i, 
      1]], (G1[[i + 1, 2]] - G1[[i - 1, 2]])/(G1[[i + 1, 1]] - 
       G1[[i - 1, 1]])}, {i, 2, Length[G1] - 1}];
ListPlot[DoS, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

You can smoothen the derivative afterwards:

```
ListPlot[MovingAverage[DoS, 5], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

which is a quite pleasing result.

---

Or smoothing and `Interpolation`:

```
gi = Interpolation @ G1

dom = gi["Domain"][[1]]

Plot[gi'[x], {x, dom[[1]], dom[[2]]}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

---

To display the method suggested by [Rahul in the comments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128320/density-of-states-from-numerical-integration-and-then-differentiation/128324#comment347134_128320):

```
reg = ListPlot[#, Frame -> True] &@
    Table[{x, m[x]}, {x, 0.01, 1.7, 0.01}]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {262.235, Null}

Faster, but

```
reg
```

[image]

has an outlier and plateaus on the right.

Comment: Use NIntegrate with `Method -> "LocalAdaptive"`. This evaluates without any warnings.

Comment: This method causes evaluation to stall at some points, like omega = 1...but yeah, it goes on and on without warning ^^

Answer (score -1):

The function G[omega] is not smooth, but you can use the following numerical differentiation to find N[omega]:

```
Clear[f]
ComputenumericalDerivative[f_, x_] := 
 Block[{xn, xn1, vars, guess, dx = 0.0001, dfdx, derivative},
  xn = x;
  dfdx = (f[xn + dx] - f[xn])/dx;
  {xn, dfdx}
  ]
(*testing*)
f[x_] := x^2 + Sin[x]
ComputenumericalDerivative[f, 1]
D[f[x], x] /. x -> 1.
Clear[f]
f[x_, y_, z_] := Sqrt[Sin[x/2.]^2. + Sin[y/2.]^2. + Sin[z/2.]^2.];
funcomega[omega_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  HeavisideTheta[omega - f[x, y, z]], {x, -Pi, Pi}, {y, -Pi, 
   Pi}, {z, -Pi, Pi}]
func = Table[{omega, funcomega[omega]}, {omega, 0, 1.7, 0.1}];
dfunc = Table[
  ComputenumericalDerivative[funcomega, omega], {omega, 0, 1.7, 0.1}]
ListLinePlot[{func, dfunc}, Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic, 
 PlotLegends -> {"G[\[Omega]]", "N[\[Omega]]"}]
```

Comment: I don't think the output (obtained in 543 sec) is very pleasing: https://imgur.com/a/jLwfQ